# How to start Gazebo Simulator with Autoware [closed]

Tags: gazebo, simulation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am following this [tutorial](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/Gazebo-Simulation-Start)  to use Gazebo Simulator with Autoware. A video tutorial has been given which is very very hard to see.

Also it says 'Launch the Autoware Launcher'. Does that say to launch Autoware Runtime Manager??

Is there any alternative documentation for Gazebo Simulator with Autoware?

Please advise! Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348888/how-to-start-gazebo-simulator-with-autoware-%5Bclosed%5D/) by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on 2020-04-09**:
Did you already see this: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/Gazebo-Simulation-Start ?

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-04-09**:
Hi @GeorgNo,

Yes, that's the tutorial I have followed which I also mentioned in my question too. I tried zooming into the video and got something. May I please know if this is the right command to launch Autoware Launcher.

```
rosrun autoware_launcher main
```

Please advise! Thank you!

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-04-10**:
This command seems to be working @GeorgNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the command :

```
rosrun autoware_launcher main
```

---

Originally posted by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) with karma: 64 on 2020-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0